# Correct syntax to add multiple items in ListTile title?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm returning the Title, but also a text label. Is the '+' correct to use here?
It runs in Android emulator.

```
return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Text(this.noteList[position].date),
            title: Text(
              'TEXT HERE: ' + this.noteList[position].title,
              style: titleStyle,
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dart string interpolation like this

```
Text('TEXT HERE: ${this.noteList[position].title}');
```

if it's not an object, you can use like this

```
String title = 'My title';
Text('TEXT HERE: $title');
```

for more info, you can read an excellent blog [here](https://flutterrdart.com/dart-strings-literals-and-string-interpolation/)